# deinitialize audio recording started via getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, webrtc, audio-streaming

I'm trying to create audio stream from browser and send it to server.

Here is the code:

```
let recording = false;
let localStream = null;
const session = {
  audio: true,
  video: false
};

function  start () {
    recording = true;
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(session, initializeRecorder, onError);
  }

function stop () {
    recording = false;
    localStream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
}

function initializeRecorder (stream) {
  localStream = stream;
  const audioContext = window.AudioContext;
  const context = new audioContext();
  const audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(localStream);
  const bufferSize = 2048;
  // create a javascript node
  const recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
  // specify the processing function
  recorder.onaudioprocess = recorderProcess;
  // connect stream to our recorder
  audioInput.connect(recorder);
  // connect our recorder to the previous destination
  recorder.connect(context.destination);
}

function onError (e) {
  console.log('error:', e);
}
function recorderProcess (e) {
  if (!recording) return;
  const left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  // send left to server here (socket.io can do the job). We dont need stereo.
}
```

when function `start` is fired, the samples can be catched in `recorderProcess`
when function `stop` is fired, the mic icon in browser disappears, but...

unless I put `if (!recording) return` in the beginning of `recorderProcess`, it still process samples.

Unfortunately it's not a solution at all - the samples are still being received by `recordingProcess` and if I fire `start` functiono once more, it will get all samples from previous stream and from new one.

My question is:

**How can I stop/start recording without such issue?**

or if it's not best solution

**How can I totally remove stream in `stop` function, to safely initialize it again anytime?**

Comment: you can try stopping the stream through `stream.stop()`

Comment: `stream.stop()` is deprecated, and it doesn't solve the problem anyway :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recorder.disconnect() should help.

You might want to consider the new MediaRecorder functionality in Chrome Canary shown at https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/record/ (currently video-only I think) instead of the WebAudio API.

Comment: Thanks. That works as expected. I will look into MediaRecorder. It looks promising, with nice promise API and settings allow for audio-only, but the drawback of using canary as a platform in production is a concern.